# Negotiate authentication is currently disabled

Tags: windows, powershell, winrm

I was trying yo use `winrm` in PowerShell and deactivate all the auth in client and service. After that I enabled them from GP and also in registry but it's still showing this message:

> The WinRM client cannot process the request. Negotiate authentication is currently disabled in the client configuration. Change the client configuration and try the request again. If this is a request for the local configuration, use one of the enabled authentication mechanisms still enabled. To use Kerberos, specify the local computer name as the remote destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

Use Group Policy:

Computer > Policies > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Remote Management > WinRM Service:
Disallow Negotiate Authentication: Disabled.

Comment: Tried the answer and restarted computer. This morning I couldn't get to a server because "Kerberos auth is not enabled", now it's "Negotiate auth is not enabled".   I enabled (or rather Disabled the Disable {auth method}) each authentication message as they came up, but changing those in gpedit.msc (where you have specified in the answer) doesn't seem to work.